# Error in Fargate configuration file: FargateECSTaskDefinition

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate

I'm using `sls` with AWS Fargate. I'm trying use `sls deploy -v` but am getting an error in my `fargate-template.yml` when I try to set the `Memory` property under `FargateECSTaskDefinition`. Here's the relevant `yml` section:

```
FargateECSTaskDefinition:
    Type: "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition"
    Properties:
      Cpu: 256
      Memory: 512 MB
```

And here's the error I get:

```
An error occurred: FargateECSTaskDefinition - Resource handler returned message: "Invalid request provided: Create TaskDefinition: Invalid 'memory' setting for task. (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameterException; Request ID: f4d1c13d-1885-4157-bf21-4299b06cf3ff; Proxy: null)" (RequestToken: b872e59f-4329-35ed-5191-cfb0c486f49f, HandlerErrorCode: InvalidRequest).
```

Setting `Memory: 1GB` works without a problem. I tried both `Memory: 512 MB` and `Memory: 512MB`, thinking that the space would make a difference. Both returned an error though. I'm following [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/create-task-definition.html) documentation, which suggests that a combination of 256 CPU units and `512 MB` memory is compatible, so I'm not sure what the issue could be.

The difference between 512MB and 1GB is trivial from a cost perspective, but at this point I want to solve this on principle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In CloudFormation the valid values are listed [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ecs-taskdefinition.html#cfn-ecs-taskdefinition-memory). It should be:

```
FargateECSTaskDefinition:
    Type: "AWS::ECS::TaskDefinition"
    Properties:
      Cpu: 256
      Memory: 512
```

Comment: went perfectly - thanks (as usual, at this point) for the help :)